# Content-Disposition response header in DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-download-manager, android-jetpack

I have to download a file and was using downloadManager for it. The filename for the file resides in the Content-Disposition of the response header.

Is there anyway of accessing the response header from DownloadManager.Request class or downloadManager could support this out of the box.

I don't want to make a HEAD api call to the server and increase the server hit count. We can assume we don't have HEAD call functionality.

Comment: Seems not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe have a look to [OkHttp3](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) instead.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.1'
```